# Avoiding two if statements for same condition with common code in between

Tags: python, coding-style, if-statement

This is a problem I run into often, and am looking for the best solution. I will have code like this (python):

```
def func(var, opt):
    if opt:
        var = var.set_opt(opt)

    result = var.get_result()

    if opt:
        return [r[0] for r in result] # arbitrary
    else:
        return result
```

What is a good, general practice, way to avoid this double if statement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid repeating a condition in methods that use it differently?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/333361/how-to-avoid-repeating-a-condition-in-methods-that-use-it-differently)

Comment: Does `var.set_opt(opt)` change what `var.get_result()` returns?

Answer (score 3):

For this case, I think the following makes the most sense.  Your need for the two ifs is based on trying to reuse the same unnecessary variable in two distinct execution paths.

```python
def func(var, opt):
    if opt:
        return [r[0] for r in var.set_opt(opt).get_result()]
    else:
        return var.get_result()
```

I don't know if there is a general rule but this tends to be a smell.  I'd rather see to independent blocks of code with some repetition than code where separate paths are weaved together like this.

Answer (score 3):

We can resolve the *else* first, which in my opinion, is the problem. I didn't see any reason to leave it for the end.

```
def func(var, opt):
    if opt is None:
        return var.get_result()

    result = var.set_opt(opt).get_result()
    return [r[0] for r in result] # arbitrary
```

I'm afraid I can't give you a more sophisticated answer because it would depends on the real code and whether the order of the *if/else* can be altered for a quick resolution of the function.

---

I'm not familiar with Python. I have searched a bit and I came to the conclusion that `if opt is None` is the opposite to `if opt`.  Feel free of correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: But now you are duplicating `get_result()` which is just shifting the problem, not eliminating it.

Comment: Where is duplicated?

Comment: `What is a good, general practice, way to avoid this double if statement?`. The problem is the doble if, no the two calls to the get_result()

Answer (score 0):

If this is your entire function, you can just break it into two pieces:

```
def func(var):
    return result = var.get_result()
```

and

```
def funcWithOpt(var, opt):
    var = var.set_opt(opt)
    result = var.get_result()
    return [r[0] for r in result]
```

If it's longer, you can use subfunctions for the different parts.

---

**However**, you should begin with asking yourself *if* this is a problem at all. Performance is not an issue, checking if `opt` exists is inexpensive. If you have a boolean *function* you need to check, you can just call that function once and 'cache' it in a variable. The function might be slightly longer with this double `if` statement, but it's readable and that definitely counts for something.

Comment: `funcWithOpt` does nothing to prevent opt from being none.

Comment: @CandiedOrange ah, blame my lack of Python skills. Is there any way of making it required?

Comment: Python isn't statically typed. You'd have to test and throw an exception.

Comment: Yes, through if statements, and now you're back to the beginning